# python mock: configure spec of a mock object

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have an instance method which initiates an object of another class. For ex,

```
import module_two
class One:
    def start(self):
        self.two = module_two.Two()
```

I am patching One class in my test cases

```
@patch('module_one.One', autospec=True)
def test_one(patched_one):
    two = patched_one.return_value

    # Following method should raise error, but doesn't
    two.any_random_non_existing_method()
```

As mentioned, `two.any_random_non_existing_method()` does not raise any error because `two` Mock object does not have any spec assigned.

How can I assign spec to the `two` object.? I am looking for something like following snippet.

```
    # note: configure_spec actually doesn't exist.!
    two.configure_spec(module_two.Two)
    two.any_random_non_existing_method() # Error.!
```

Comment: Since your `patched_one` object is already a mock object, it shouldn't be hard to set `patched_one.two = mock.Mock(spec='module_two.Two')`. I'm having trouble following why in your test you have `two = patched_one.return_value` though since your `One` class doesn't seem to behave like that.

Comment: So, does that mean specifications can only be applied when initializing the mock object and it is not possible afterwards.?

Comment: Ah I see, that's your main goal. Would `mock_add_spec` work for you? https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_add_spec

Comment: It did work.! I completely missed `mock_add_spec` method in mock. Thanks.! With the method, we can configure specifications on an existing mock object.

Comment: K, glad it worked! I'll put it as an answer for future visitors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some comments, looks like `mock_add_spec` would work for you:

> Add a spec to a mock. spec can either be an object or a list of strings. Only attributes on the spec can be fetched as attributes from the mock.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_add_spec

Here's how it should look:

```
# Add specifications on existing mock object
two.mock_add_spec(module_two.Two)
two.any_random_non_existing_method() # Error.!
```

Comment: Can you please also post the snippet as a solution for the question's snippet. Thanks.!